# How to disable cdkDrag dragging animation?

Tags: css, angular, angular-cdk

I have an example where I used cdkDrag.I dont wanna see anything when I start to drag.How can I disable CSS classes which applied on dragging state?

[image]

Above you can see there's a little view of my item when I drag it and I dont wanna see.How can it be possible?I couldnt find which CSS class should be disabled.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbls7d-rih7te?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html

Comment: When you start dragging, ```.cdk-drag-preview``` class activated.
And when you release item, ```.cdk-drag-animating``` class activated. Change ```.cdk-drag-preview``` display property to none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the dragging preview with `cdkDragPreview` directive, described in [Angular Materials D&D  CdkDragPreview docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDragPreview).

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>
    {{movie.title}}
    <img *cdkDragPreview [src]="movie.poster" [alt]="movie.title">
  </div>
</div>
```

See example [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lmgeexpanlen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-custom-preview-example.html).

---

For your example you can add an element into your `cdkDrag` root element.

E.g.:

```
...
<tr *ngFor="let feed of todo;let index = index" cdkDrag  (cdkDragStarted)="started($event)">
          <span *cdkDragPreview>Test</span>
                    <td>
...
```

Check your adapted [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbls7d-fnw7nh?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html).